# Can't access to my app after migrating profile page to fan page

Tags: facebook-apps, administration, facebook-page

I have some issue with Facebook.

Recently, as recommanded by Facebook, I decided to migrate my Profile Page to a Fan Page.

The problem is that now, I can't access to my app administration page (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXX). I am redirected to http://www.facebook.com/browse/admined_pages/?id=XXXXX.

Is there a way to solve this problem ? (for example, attaching my existing apps to an other profile ?).

Thanks a lot,

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have added another profile as admin of the app before switching.

From https://www.facebook.com/help?page=213602951994043

"You won't remain the admin of any groups or apps you managed from your personal account. Be sure to add new admins before converting. Additionally, content on your timeline (ex. photo albums, profile information, etc.) will not be transferred"

Sorry for the bad news :/

(You can always create a new app, you should still have the code, right?)

Comment: I will test with other accounts I have, maybe one of them is admin of the app ... I cross my fingers :)

The app is only used because I set Facebook Connect on my web site.